# Ошибка в распределении

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Имеется код

```
public void SetTeam(Player player)
        {
            foreach (Team team in Teams.ToArray())
            {
                if (team.IsFull())
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!team.InCommand(player))
                    {
                        team.AddPlayer(player);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Данным кодом я заполняю команды игроками, их всего две, по 1 или 2 игрока, в зависимости от режима.
Вот так распределяю:

```
foreach (Player player in GetPlayers().ToArray())
            {
                SetTeam(player);
                Prespawn(player);
                TeleportToTeamSpawn(player);
            }
```

Но бывает что игроков распределяет некорректно, бывает что одного игрока бросает в разные команд. Распределение проводиться в таймере.

***Team.cs***

```
public class Team
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "0";

        public int MaxPlayers { get; set; } = 0;

        public bool IsEliminated { get; set; } = false;

        public Vector3 Spawn { get; set; } = Vector3.Zero;
        public Vector3 Portal { get; set; } = Vector3.Zero;

        public int Points { get; set; } = 0;

        public List<Player> Players = new List<Player>();

        public Team(int maxplayers, string name)
        {
            MaxPlayers = maxplayers;
            Name = name;
        }
        public void AddPlayer(Player player)
        {
            if (IsFull()) return;
            if (!Players.Contains(player))
            {
                Players.Add(player);
            }
        }
        public void RemovePlayer(Player player)
        {
            if (Players.Contains(player))
            {
                Players.Remove(player);
            }
        }
        public bool IsFull()
        {
            if (Players.Count == MaxPlayers)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public void Reset()
        {
            IsEliminated = false;
            Points = 0;
            Players.Clear();
            Players = null;
            Players = new List<Player>();
        }
        public bool InCommand(Player player)
        {
            if (Players.Find((x) => x.Username.ToLower() == player.Username.ToLower()) is Player)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Есть догадка что это происходит из-за разных потоков.

Comment: Очень плохо задан вопрос. "Распределение проводиться в таймере." - Вы думаете, нам все стало понятно? Это фраза порождает самые худшие подозрения.

Comment: Таймер который вызывает эту функцию

Comment: Я Вам сейчас за такое объяснение минус поставлю.

Comment: Ваши вопросы (этот и предыдущий про флаг с задержкой) очень похожи между собой. Вы не даете нам общей картины, а вырываете куски кода с минимальным объяснением того какой алгоритм вы хотите реализовать. Это как спрашивать у своих подписчиков в инстаграме, показывая им фоточки снятые на мобильник через иллюминатор, о том, а в правильном ли направлении идет яхта или летит самолет.

Comment: а что тут не ясно?

Comment: "...бывает что одного игрока бросает в разные команд." Я так понимаю речь идет о том, что один и тот же игрок оказывается сразу в двух командах, так? Если проблема в этом, то тогда у вас просто неправильно реализовано распределение игроков. Т.е. при внесении игрока в ту или иную команду вы либо должны его через какое-то свойство помечать игрока, что он уже принадлежит какой-то команде, а значит не подлежит дальнейшему распределению, либо после добавления в команду динамично удалять его из коллекции еще нераспределенных игроков.

Comment: можно с вами в чат?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что догадка правильная. 
Класс `List<T>` имеет свойство `SyncRoot`
Попробуй переписать все свои обращения к методам коллекции следующим образом...

```
lock (Players.SyncRoot) 
 {
      // Access the collection.
 }
```